# Trialdivision for Proth's numbers

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I want to test Proth's numbers for primality.
These are numbers of the form $h\cdot 2^k+1$ for a natural $k$ and an odd $h<2^k$.
I am wondering whether I can find a faster method than the "normal" trialdivision.
So my thought is:
Let $p$ be an odd prime. Then we have
$$
h\cdot 2^k+1\equiv 0 \pmod p
\Leftrightarrow
h\cdot 2^k\equiv -1 \pmod p
\Leftrightarrow
h\cdot 2^k\equiv -1 \pmod p
$$

So I could check whether
$$2^k \equiv -(h^{-1})\pmod p$$
or
$$
h\equiv -2^{-k}\pmod p
$$
is true.
I wrote a short script, but is is very slow.
Is that normal or is there a chance to get an improved trial division by these congruences?

Comment: Are you aware of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proth%27s_theorem and the suggestions there?

Comment: @Henry yes but it does not match my question